# Linux - ways to invoke function in a different process

Tags: linux

I am trying to find the different ways a process A can invoke a function and possibly get result back from a process B (preferably on the same machine).

I know one of them is referred to as RPC. Linux has several IPC mechanisms, like pipes, shared memory etc. but most of them just allow to share some data. Even with UNIX domain sockets .. I see examples indicating only data transfer is possible (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is it possible to do Linux RPC on the same machine between different processes ? Is there any other alternative to use on the same machine ?

(Reference to any tutorial would be helpful)

Comment: "Data" could be a command such as "find your function called fliplify, call it with these two arguments and tell me the result" or maybe you refer to the function by a number in a pre-agreed list of choices.  A program is just data that someone has agreed to follow as instructions, so with cooperation of the other process you can indeed make function calls across the process boundary.  To do it without cooperation, look at `ptrace`

Answer (score 0):

In languages with headers, or protocols (objective-c) you can define these interfaces such that different processes can formally reference the contracts simply by importing those headers.

Otherwise, yes, you can use a less formal approach as indicated by Chris Stratton in his comment.